# How can I read a request JSON body so I can work with it after responding to the request?

Tags: json, http, ssl, go

I am writing an HTTP server to handle Cisco Meraki Scanning API. It is a push API, in which Cisco periodically calls your endpoint with a POST request and a JSON body. The API must be able to respond to this POST request in less than 500ms. If not, Cisco will stop sending you data, and you can't recover that information.

So, I have been looking for ways to handle these requests as fast as I can.

The first thing I did was decouple the processing of the JSON body by using a queue. I take the Body from the request, put it in the queue, and respond. Then, several workers will process the body and store it on S3 asynchronously. I also tried to make the server as simple as possible.

Most requests work in less than 500ms, but some don't. Looking at where I am, the only thing that comes to mind to improve these times is to process the body of the request faster.

The whole server is available on this link: [meraki_endpoint.go](https://github.com/guzmonne/meraki_endpoint/blob/master/meraki_endpoint.go). And this is how I am handling the request body at the moment:

```golang
func handleData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, jobs chan job) {
  var devicesSeen DevicesSeen
  // I am using "github.com/json-iterator/go" instead of "encoding/json"
  err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&devicesSeen)
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Bad request - Can't Decode!", 400)
    panic(err)
  }
  // Create Job and push the work into the Job Channel
  go func() {
    jobs <- job{devicesSeen}
  }()
  // Render success
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}
```

At the moment I am decoding the JSON as I read if from the body, instead of reading it and store it as a list of bytes using `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)`. After trying both ways, I couldn't find a significant speed improvement.

How can I improve the performance of the server? Or, how can I read the body of the request faster so I can work on it later on the queue?

---

**Edit #1**

I moved my stack to another AWS region, closer to the source of the data, and the roundtrip time descended to a fifth of what it was before.

Comment: Why not repsond without evern decoding the JSON assuming the request is OK? BTW is that 500 millisecs or 500 microsecs - I can't see why it would take half a sec to respond unless there are other things going on.

Comment: It's 500 milliseconds round trip time. I've now modified that code and instead of decoding it I went back to just reading it, and passing the byte buffer to the queue. Using this: `devicesSeen, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` It seems to be working faster. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you could prevent a few allocations by preallocating a `[]byte` based on the content length header of the request. Another solution would be to simply hand down `r.Body` down a channel, as it _should_ survive leaving the request scope. But in general, the roundtrip is much more likely to increase because of reasons not to be found in your code. Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: It would be helpful to have some testdata

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I have benchmark it from my setup, and it should work. Most of the time is spent on the SSL handshake, and not processing the request. I have my doubts though about passing the `r.Body` into a channel, shouldn't be responding to the request close the reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you could read the body much faster, specially if you already tried just doing a `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` instead of decoding it.

And since from what you observe most requests are indeed fast, probably your problem is not that `handleData` function.

Here are some things to try:

- Play with different "max_workers" settings

If the amount of pending requests is too large, even though goroutines are cheap they do take some memory so your server might slow down anyway, specially if garbage collection plays a role there, which takes us to the next bullet.

- Try to profile GC, or else play with different settings

Here you have the runtime documentation including the `GOGC` variable you can try tuning, plus some flags you can try using to profile the GC pauses (see `gctrace` flag there for example)

https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/

These blogs might also help, they detail some issues they were seeing with GC at high processing volume and how they worked around those improving GC performance:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/go-dont-collect-my-garbage/

https://blog.twitch.tv/go-memory-ballast-how-i-learnt-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-heap-26c2462549a2

- Scale horizontally

You don't describe your whole setup, but probably you have a group of servers load-balancing? If volume is high one possibility is that the amount of servers you have can't handle the load, in that case you can try adding more servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The setup is indeed working inside an auto-scaling group in AWS using m5a.large EC2 instances, with an ALB in front. I'll try your second suggestion.